# android how to access customized listview item

Tags: android

i tryied to  custom my ListView , so i use this item layout 「 list_item.xml」

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/pause"
                            android:src="@drawable/stop"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:onClick="pauseBtn_onClick"
                            />
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/play"
                            android:src="@drawable/play"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:onClick="playBtn_onClick"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

just as  what you saw, there are 2 images in this layout, what i wanna do is,

when user click any item , the play_icon(the second image in the listview item) , will

disappear.

so i write code as the following :

```
mp3_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        { 
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View _view, int index , long arg3) 
            { 
                String _url = musicList.get(index).get("link").toString();
                LinearLayout _container = (LinearLayout)mp3_listView.getChildAt(index);
                RelativeLayout _container2 = (RelativeLayout) _container.getChildAt(1);
                ImageView img = (ImageView)_container2.getChildAt(1);
                img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(tabDigTest.this , "GG : "+_container.findViewById(R.id.play) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
}
```

but something strange occurred .... more than one item's img be hidden because of the:

```
img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

i don't why because i only set one img to INVISIBLE ......i think i need help O_o

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the user click, I guess you set up an [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29).

```
ListView lv = (fecth your list vieW)
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //you might want to use 'view' here
  }
});
```

In the onItemClick method, the view parameter is the view you returned in your ListAdapter's getView method. So if say, you have returned a LinearLayout containing three childrens with id ("textview", "imageview1", "imageview2"), you would simply call view.findViewById(R.id.imageview1) to retrieve the first ImageView.

Comment: Well, can you describe a bit more ? Or upload your code somewhere ?